# Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly -ubuntu -12.04

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, lsusb

Ubuntu 12.04 
 Bluetooth is not searching  an device

```
dmesg | grep Blue  
[   11.005902] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   11.005919] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.005978] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.006323] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.006328] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.387477] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[   13.394719] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   18.867503] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   18.867515] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   18.867521] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   19.461578] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.461582] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.461593] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

with lsusb

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6473 Microdia
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the results from `lsusb` as firmware for Broadcom devices depend on their ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get your firmware

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ryy3ir1tby6wrf/fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd
sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/
sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
```

And then we reload the btusb module

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

And now check dmesg to see if firmware loaded or has errors

```
dmesg | tail
```

This might show another firmware loading error if your kernel is expecting   a different file name

Comment: A lot of Broadcom bluetooth devices need firmware that is only avaiable through windows drivers.  You can check out the answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189790/how-can-i-get-the-bluetooth-working-on-my-lenovo-yoga-3 for some details.

Comment: this worked for my Dell Inspiron 15R 5520. Just in case somebody else is also facing the same problem. Thanks @Jeremy31

Comment: [   21.665860] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 2815.615210] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff88000f516a80 failed to resubmit (2)
[ 2829.643028] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x213c tx timeout
[ 2837.642455] Bluetooth: fail to load firmware    --- Had exact similar problem. After trying these steps, bluetooth still not working. Log above.

Comment: @Ravi try `sudo cp /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/BCM.hcd` then reboot